# Subscribe to next() call

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

and many Oberservers are listening to it and do something. What I want to do is to wait for the Observers to finish and then do something else.

```
mySubject.next();
```

And then wait for a callback of the Observers or anything.

Comment: see async await

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is to wait for the Observers to finish and then do
>   something else

For this there is a complete-callback. If your subject will call `mySubject.complete()` a complete-callback is called:

```
mySubject.subscribe(null,null, () => { /* complete */ })
```

Comment: Or instead of passing `null`, `null`, you can pass an object `mySubject.subscribe({ complete: () => { /* complete */ } })`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to emit something then wait for all the subscribers to complete before doing other thing.

According to [Rxjs subject definition](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject), a Subject is like an event emitter : it's unidirectional.

I'm afraid what you want to achieve here is not possible at all with this method.

You should have a look at [ngrx-store](https://ngrx.io/) which gives you the capability to dispatch actions and effects.

Answer (score -1):

You can subscribe to your subject like this;

```
mySubject.subscribe(data => {    
  //You can do what you want here    
})
```